# Find numbers present in at least two of the three arrays

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

How might I approach solving the following problem:

> Create an array of integers that are contained in at least two of the given arrays.

For example:

```
int[] a1 = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };          
int[] a2 = new int[] { 5, 10, 11, 8 };           
int[] a3 = new int[] { 1, 7, 6, 4, 5, 3, 11 };
```

must give a result array

```
int[] result = new int[] {1, 3, 4, 5, 11}
```

P.S. i'm interested in suggestions on how I might approach this ("algorithm"), not what Java utils might give me the answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. put `a1` numbers in a `Map<Integer,Integer> count`, using the value as the key, and setting the count to `1`
2. Put `a2` numbers into the same map. If an item does not exist, assign the count of `1`, otherwise assign it the existing count + 1
3. Put `a3` numbers into the same map. If an item does not exist, assign the count of `1`, otherwise assign it the existing count + 1
4. Go through the entries in a map, and output all keys where the value is greater than one.

This algorithm is amortized linear time in the combined number of elements in the three arrays.

If the numbers in the three arrays are limited to, say, 1000 or another relatively small number, you could avoid using collections at all, but use a potentially more expensive algorithm based on the upper limit of your numbers: replace the map with an array `counts[MAX_NUM+1]`, and then run the same algorithm, like this:

```
int[] counts = new int[MAX_NUM+1];
for (int a : a1) counts[a]++;
for (int a : a2) counts[a]++;
for (int a : a3) counts[a]++;
for (int i = 0 ; i != MAX_NUM+1 ; i++) {
    if (counts[i] > 1) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think he wants to avoid using the collections library

Comment: Im guessing this answer would be beyond the learning curve of the original quesion. With other words, the chapter Maps has not yet been reached.

Comment: @Sunil I am not sure about that - he says he's looking for an algorithm that does not use Java's utils, but he says nothing about collections. I'll expand with an array-based solution, though.

Comment: @Sunil OP can always implement his own `Map` implementation if he wants to be miserable.

Comment: @John Thanks for the edit, I have no idea why it has been rejected.

Comment: Took me a couple of read throughs to understand the non-collections code. +1 Clever.

Comment: you method won't work if a array has duplicate emlements

Answer (score 3):

You can look at the 3 arrays as [*sets*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29) and find each element that is in the [intersection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_%28set_theory%29) of some pair of sets.

basically, you are looking for `(set1 [intersection] set2) [union] (set2 [intersection] set3) [union] (set1 [intersection] set2)`

I agree that **it might not be the easiest** way to achieve what you are after, but **being able to reduce one problem to another** is a technique every programmer should master, and this solution should be very **educating**.

Comment: Brilliant solution

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this without collections would be to take an element from an array, iterate over the remaining two arrays to see if a duplicate is found (and then break and move to the next element). You need to do this for two out of the three arrays as by the time you move to the third one, you would already have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I like drawing Venn diagramms. You know that diagram with three intersecting circles, e.g. see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aVenn_diagram_gr_la_ru.svg).

You then see that the complement is easier to describe:
Those elements which only exist in one array, are not interesting.

So you could build a frequency list (i.e. key = element, value = count of in how many arrays you found it [for the first time]) in a hash map, and then in a final pass pick all elements which occured more than once.

For simplicity I used sets. If your arrays contain multiple entries of the same value, you have to ignore those extra occurences when you build the frequency list.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically this can be solved as follows:

You can construct three sets using each of the three arrays, so duplicated entries in each array will only occur once in each set. And then the entries that appear at least in two of the three sets are solutions. So they are given by

```
(S_1 intersect S_2) union (S_2 intersect S_3) union (S_3 intersect S_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about the question and the different strategies you might use:

1. Go through each entry in each array, if that entry is NOT already in the "duplicates" result, then see if that entry is in each of the remaining arrays.  Add to duplicates if it is and return to next integer
2. Create an array of non-duplicates by adding an entry from each array (and if it is already there, putting it in the duplicates array).
3. Use another creative strategy of your own

Answer (score 0):

An approach could be like this: 
1.Sort all the arrays.
2.For each combination of arrays do this

Let us consider the first two arrays A,B.   Let a be A's size.
Also take a third array or vector to store our result

```
  for i=0-->a-1 {

   Search for A[i] in B   using    binarySearch.

   if A[i] exists in B then insert A[i] into our result vector

   }
```

Repeat the same process for (B,C) and (C,A).

Now sort & Traverse the result vector from the end, remove the elements which have the property

```
     result[i] = result[i-1]
```

The final vector is the required result.

Time Complexity Analysis:

```
   T(n) = O(nlog(n)) for Sorting where n is the highest array size among the given three 

   For searching each element of an array in other sorted array T(n) = n * O(log n)

   T(n) = O(n (log n)) for sorting the result and O(n) for traversing 

   So overall time complexity is O(n log(n)); and space complexity is O(n)
```

Please  correct me of I am wrong

Answer (score 0):

In Java:

Will write one without using java.utils shortly.

Meantime a solution using java.utils:

```
public static void twice(int[] a, int[] b, int[] c) {

    //Used Set to remove duplicates
    Set<Integer> setA = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        setA.add(a[i]);
    }

    Set<Integer> setB = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        setB.add(b[i]);
    }

    Set<Integer> setC = new HashSet<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        setC.add(c[i]);
    }

    //Logic to fill data into a Map
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    for (Integer val : setA) {
        map.put(val, 1);
    }

    for (Integer val : setB) {
        if (map.get(val) != null) {
            int count = map.get(val);
            count++;
            map.put(val, count);
        } else {
            map.put(val, 1);
        }
    }

    for (Integer val : setC) {
        if (map.get(val) != null) {
            int count = map.get(val);
            count++;
            map.put(val, count);
        } else {
            map.put(val, 1);
        }
    }

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry2 : map.entrySet()) {

        //if (entry2.getValue() == 2) {  //Return the elements that are present in two out of three arrays.
        if(entry2.getValue() >= 2) {     //Return elements that are present **at least** twice in the three arrays.
            System.out.print(" " + entry2.getKey());
        }
    }
}
```

Change condition in last for loop in case one need to return the elements that are present in two out of three arrays. Say:

```
int[] a = { 2, 3, 8, 4, 1, 9, 8 };
int[] b = { 6, 5, 3, 7, 9, 2, 1 };
int[] c = { 5, 1, 8, 2, 4, 0, 5 };

Output: { 3, 8, 4, 5, 9 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here goes without any java.util library:

```
public static void twice(int[] a, int[] b, int[] c) {
    int[] a1 = removeDuplicates(a);
    int[] b1 = removeDuplicates(b);
    int[] c1 = removeDuplicates(c);

    int totalLen = a1.length + b1.length +c1.length;
    int[][] keyValue = new int[totalLen][2];

    int index = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<a1.length; i++, index++)
    {
        keyValue[index][0] = a1[i]; //Key
        keyValue[index][1] = 1;     //Value
    }

    for(int i=0; i<b1.length; i++)
    {
        boolean found = false;
        int tempIndex = -1;
        for(int j=0; j<index; j++)
        {
            if (keyValue[j][0] == b1[i]) {
                found = true;
                tempIndex = j;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(found){
            keyValue[tempIndex][1]++;
        } else {
            keyValue[index][0] = b1[i]; //Key
            keyValue[index][1] = 1;     //Value
            index++;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<c1.length; i++)
    {
        boolean found = false;
        int tempIndex = -1;
        for(int j=0; j<index; j++)
        {
            if (keyValue[j][0] == c1[i]) {
                found = true;
                tempIndex = j;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(found){
            keyValue[tempIndex][1]++;
        } else {
            keyValue[index][0] = c1[i]; //Key
            keyValue[index][1] = 1;     //Value
            index++;
        }
    }

    for(int i=0; i<index; i++)
    {
        //if(keyValue[i][1] == 2)
        if(keyValue[i][1] >= 2)
        {
            System.out.print(keyValue[i][0]+" ");
        }
    }
}

public static int[] removeDuplicates(int[] input) {
    boolean[] dupInfo = new boolean[500];//Array should not have any value greater than 499.
    int totalItems = 0;

    for( int i = 0; i < input.length; ++i ) {
        if( dupInfo[input[i]] == false ) {
            dupInfo[input[i]] = true;
            totalItems++;
        }
    }

    int[] output = new int[totalItems];
    int j = 0;
    for( int i = 0; i < dupInfo.length; ++i ) {
        if( dupInfo[i] == true ) {
            output[j++] = i;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple and could be done for n different arrays the same way:

```
    public static void compute(int[] a1, int[] a2, int[] a3) {
        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        fillMap(map, a1);
        fillMap(map, a2);
        fillMap(map, a3);

        for (Integer key : map.keySet()) {
            System.out.print(map.get(key) > 1 ? key + ", " : "");
        }
    }

    public static void fillMap(HashMap<Integer, Integer> map, int[] a) {
        for (int i : a) {
            if (map.get(i) == null) {
                map.put(i, 1);
                continue;
            }
            int count = map.get(i);
            map.put(i, ++count);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun atLeastTwo(a: ArrayList<Int>, b: ArrayList<Int>, c: ArrayList<Int>): List<Int>{
    val map = a.associateWith { 1 }.toMutableMap()
    b.toSet().forEach { map[it] = map.getOrDefault(it, 0) + 1 }
    c.toSet().forEach{ map[it] = map.getOrDefault(it, 0) + 1 }
    return map.filter { it.value == 2 }.map { it.key }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can do it like this:

```
let sa = new Set(),
    sb = new Set(),
    sc = new Set();
A.forEach(a => sa.add(a));
B.forEach(b => sb.add(b));
C.forEach(c => sc.add(c));
let res = new Set();
sa.forEach((a) => {
    if (sb.has(a) || sc.has(a)) res.add(a);
})
sb.forEach((b) => {
    if (sa.has(b) || sc.has(b)) res.add(b);
})
sc.forEach((c) => {
    if (sa.has(c) || sb.has(c)) res.add(c);
})
let arr = Array.from(res.values());
arr.sort((i, j) => i - j)
return arr
```